# How can I unit test components in AngularJS2 "final"?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angular, typescript, components

I'm currently trying to write a unit test for a very simple AngularJs2 component.

This is the Typescript:

```
// cell.component.ts
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import Cell from './cell';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'cell',
    templateUrl: 'cell.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['cell.component.css']
})

export class CellComponent {
    @Input()
    cell = Cell;
}
```

This is the template:

```
<!-- cell.component.html -->
<div class="ticTacToe--board-cell ticTacToe--board-cell--{{cell.background}}">
    <div class="ticTacToe--board-cell--{{cell.displayMarker()}}">{{cell.displayMarker()}}</div>
</div>
```

And here is my current test:

```
// cell.component.spec.ts
    import { async, inject, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
    import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';
    import { ReflectiveInjector } from '@angular/core';

    import { CellComponent } from './cell.component';
    import Cell from './cell';
    import Marker from './marker.enum';

    //TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting());

    describe('CellComponent', () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                declarations: [CellComponent]
            });
        });

        it ('should render a cell', async(() => {
            TestBed.compileComponents().then(() => {
                // Arrange
                const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CellComponent);
                const componentUnderTest = fixture.nativeElement;
                const testId = 1; 
                const testMarker = Marker.X;
                const testCell = new Cell(1);
                testCell['marker'] = testMarker;

                // Act
                componentUnderTest.cell = testCell;

                // Assert
                fixture.detectChanges();
                expect(componentUnderTest.querySelectorAll('div.ticTacToe--board-cell').length).toBe(1);
                expect(componentUnderTest.querySelectorAll('div.ticTacToe--board-cell--background').length).toBe(1);
                expect(componentUnderTest.querySelectorAll('div.ticTacToe--board-cell--X').length).toBe(1);
                expect(componentUnderTest.querySelectorAll('div.ticTacToe--board-cell--X')[0].innerText).toBe('X');
            });
        }));
    });
```

This fails with:

> Chrome 49.0.2623 (Windows XP 0.0.0) CellComponent should render a cell
>   FAILED1] [1]     Failed: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in
>   app/cell.component.html:1:9 caused by: self.context.cell.displayMarker
>   is not a function [1]     Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error
>   in app/cell.component.html:1:9 caused by:
>   self.context.cell.displayMarker is not a function

But displayMarker is a function in my Cell class:

```
import  Marker  from './marker.enum';

export class Cell {
    id: number;
    private marker: Marker;
    private background = 'background';

    constructor(id: number) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    displayMarker() {
        return Marker[this.marker];
    }

    getMarker() {
        return this.marker;
    }

    setMarker(marker: Marker) {
        if (!this.marker) {
            this.marker = marker;
        }
    }

    declareWinner() {
        this.background = 'winner';
    }

    isEmpty() {
        return this.marker === undefined;
    }

  }

export default Cell;
```

... and when tested manually (instead of through Karma/Jasmine) this works fine.

Any ideas how I can make my unit test work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple mistakes.

1. ```
   export class CellComponent {
       @Input()
       cell = Cell;  <===========
   }
   ```

   You're assigning the `Cell` *function* to `cell`. It works at when manually testing because type information is gone, and you can assign whatever to it. So when you do pass an actual `Cell` instance to it, then it is fine. But it should be changed to use the *type* syntax

   ```
   @Input() cell: Cell;
   ```
2. ```
   const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CellComponent);
   const componentUnderTest = fixture.nativeElement;
   ```

   `fixture.nativeElement` *does not* give you the component under test, it give you the DOM element. Why do yo think you can do `componentUnderTest.querySelectorAll`?

   You should be instead be using `fixture.componentInstance` to get the component under test.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Will check into this.

Comment: Tried changing my CellComponent class per your feedback, but unfortunately the end result was exactly the same. :-(  That said, when I restarted the game itself, I noticed the transpiler is compaining about the use of async in the spec file requiring at least es2015... I don't know if that is a separate issue...

Comment: Dis you fix problem 2? As for the transpiler problem, I am not sure

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't awake yet when I make my last comment.  I re-read and reviewed my code again and it works now.  :-)  Cheers!